# Install Watchman not working with Home brew on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: react-native, homebrew, watchman

When I type with command `brew install watchman` in terminal.

It giving me this errros:

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "watchman".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: Try updating homebrew then install watchman

Comment: @HassanKandil I already updated but I still got that error.